# Error using NSMutableString property "Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablestring, declared-property

When I to append a string to an `NSMutableString` using `appendString:` I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'
```

My code is:

```
self.partialWord = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:self.wordLength];
for (int i=0; i<wordLength; i++) {
    [self.partialWord appendString:@"-"];
}
```

And in my header file:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableString *partialWord;
```

I don't understand why it says the object is immutable as it's an `NSMutableString`. Why does the `[self.partialWord appendString:@"-"];` part not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to the `copy` attribute on your property. When you assign a value to the property, it creates a copy. But the copy is made with `copy` and not `mutableCopy` so you actually end up assigning an `NSString` to the property and not an `NSMutableString`.

Get rid of `copy` on the property or implement your own custom "setter" method that calls `mutableCopy`.